# how to transfer value from one jsp page to second jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

i have one value called titleValue  at one jsp page called titleValue..i need to show this value at second jsp page.. could you please tell me how to show this value at second page or how to `x:out` `$titleValue` at second page?

this is my code at first page :

```
<x:set select="title" var="titleValue" scope="session"/>
<x:out select="$titleValue"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

- put it in the `session`. Accessible throgh `${sessionScope.titleValue}`
- pass it as a get parameter (`page.jsp?titleValue=something`). In that case it is accessible with `${param.titleValue}`

Comment: I tried this but I see "titleValue" not the exact value of titleValue when I write the following code:   <x:set select="title" var="titleValue" scope="session"/>
                           <x:out select="$titleValue"/>
                           <c:set var="com_mycompany_name2" value="$titleValue" scope="session" />
                            <c:out value='${sessionScope.com_mycompany_name2}' />
                           <x:out select="description" escapeXml="false"/>